# Powershell SQLConnection JSON Insert works in PS5 but not PS7

Tags: json, sql-server, powershell, .net-core

So I have a powershell script that calls a web api that returns data as json in which I take and push into a table in sql server.  The runtime environment is Windows Server 2016 and the script runs fine in Powershell 5, however when I run the script in Powershell 7 I get data handling errors particularly around data like a name (or in the example below the POC field) that has a single quote in it.  (i.e. Bob O'Connor).  I have tried a couple things to escape the data in sql and would like to avoid having to parse all the response in PS before inserting.

Is anyone aware of difference in the sql client between PS 5 and 7 that would cause this change in data handling or maybe a easy way to fix it?

Here is the relevant PS Code.

```
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConn.ConnectionString = 'myConnString'
$sqlConn.Open()
$sqlcmd = $sqlConn.CreateCommand()
$sqlcmd.Connection = $sqlConn
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $URL -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
$respjson = $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 -Compress
$sqlcmd.CommandText = $InsertStatement -f $respjson
$result = $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is the sql script that is used to bulk insert the json record into the table.

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @JSON = N'{0}';
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, N'$.result')
WITH ( 
Location    VARCHAR(10) '$.u_location',
ContactVerified VARCHAR(5)  '$.u_contact_verified',
POCType     VARCHAR(20) '$.u_type_of_poc',
POC         VARCHAR(50) '$.u_poc',
Active      VARCHAR(5)  '$.u_active'
);
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL Injection. Instead of copying the JSON into `{0}` in your insert statement you should be using an nvarchar(max) [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter), then you don't have to think about escaping the `'` character(s).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for the feedback.  I will review the suggestion.  I was less concerned about that since it was an internal system to system API, but it makes sense to do it the most secure way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- It's worth taking a step back and considering [AlwaysLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122/alwayslearning)'s advice: "Your code is wide open to SQL Injection. Instead of copying the JSON into `{0}` in your `INSERT` statement, you should be using an `nvarchar(max)` [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter), then you don't have to think about escaping the `'` character(s)."

As for your immediate problem:

While [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) can behave differently in principle in *PowerShell (Core) 7* (because the underlying implementation changed relative to *Windows PowerShell*), it sounds like your problem is unrelated to that:

For the resulting SQL command to work syntactically, you need to escape `'` characters in the JSON string as `''`:

```sh
$sqlcmd.CommandText = $InsertStatement -f ($respjson -replace "'", "''")
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the feedback from previous answers and comments.  Here is my revised code that converted to sql parameters for future visitors.

```
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConn.ConnectionString = 'myConnString'
$sqlConn.Open()
$sqlcmd = $sqlConn.CreateCommand()
$sqlcmd.Connection = $sqlConn
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $URL -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
$respjson = $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 -Compress
#$sqlcmd.CommandText = $InsertStatement -f $respjson
$sqlcmd.CommandText = $InsertStatement
$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter('@JSON', [Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, -1))).Value = $respjson
$sqlcmd.Prepare()
$result = $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear()
```

Add SQL file Updates

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, N'$.result')
WITH ( 
Location   VARCHAR(10) '$.u_location',
ContactVerified VARCHAR(5)  '$.u_contact_verified',
POCType     VARCHAR(20) '$.u_type_of_poc',
POC         VARCHAR(50) '$.u_poc',
Active      VARCHAR(5)  '$.u_active'
);
```

I tested both this approach and the one recommend by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) and performance is about the same.