# SQL Query not accepting variable when using NOT IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to pass a variable into a SQL NOT IN update statement to update a few table columns. I run the following commands and do not receive any errors. However, the update does the exact opposite of the commands.

```
$VMs = @()
foreach ($VM in VMs){
invoke-sqlcmd -Database $Database -server $SQLServer -Query "Update (table) set Column1= 1, Column2= 0, column3 = GETDATE() where table.vmid NOT IN ('${$vm.VMid}')"
}
```

I see that all the data is being passed into the variable. But, the NOT IN update statement is not updating my column correctly. Also, I do not receive any error messages when running my code.

Comment: It looks like you think that the syntax `IN ({Tuple})` (for example `In ('a','b','c')`) and `IN ({delimited scalar value})` (for example (`IN ('a,b,c')`) are synonyms; they are *not*. SQL Server doesn't take a delimited scalar value and split it into a tuple; it was effectively treat it as `= 'a,b,c'`.

Comment: Thank you, is there a work around for this? @Larnu

Comment: You need to join the elements of that array with `','` so the syntax is valid

Comment: If you must use `sqlcmd` then you would have to **carefully** inject the delimited values in quotes. insteadof passing `a,b,c` you would pass `'a','b','c'`. If you switch to .Net objects then you could use a table type parameter, or pass the delimited value as you are (as a parameter) and then use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the value(s).

Comment: I used NOT IN ('$($vmdetail.VMid -join ',')') but the results are the same. @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: Thats close, I believe it should look like this: `('$($vm.VMid -join "','")')`. But also if doing this, you dont need the loop, you would do `('$($VMs.VMid -join "','")')`

Comment: @Larnu would you like to answer the question? your comments provide the right guidance, the syntax for joining the array with the proper delimiters is above

Comment: In truth, I would want to use a .Net object solution to do this, @SantiagoSquarzon , as I'm a huge advocate for parameterisation (as everybody should be!), but I'm not in a position to test a Powershell script right now, hence I've deliberately not posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me build on the helpful comments by [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) and [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon).

First, the obligatory **caveat**:

- **Building SQL queries as *self-contained strings* bears the risk of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**, i.e. inadvertent execution of potentially malicious queries.
- This risk can be avoided by passing dynamic parts of the query *as parameters* to a [*parameterized statement (query)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements).
- While [`Invoke-Sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) *does* support passing parameters via its **`-Variable` parameter**, it apparently **does *not* prevent SQL injection**, due to its string-based implementation for the sake of compatibility with the SQL Server CLIs, according to [Invoke-Sqlcmd considered harmful](https://powershellstation.com/2016/01/05/invoke-sqlcmd-considered-harmful/).
- The [`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection) .NET API offers true parameterized queries, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68489705/45375).
- **If you do need to construct a self-contained query string with parameter values *embedded* in it, be sure that you either *fully control* or *implicitly trust* those values**.

---

In your particular case, given that the dynamic values are *identifiers* that you obtain yourself, there should be no security concern.

What is required in your case is to **programmatically create a `,`-separated list of the VM IDs each enclosed in '...'**, to be used as the RHS of the [`[NOT] IN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql) T-SQL operator; e.g. (I'm using `…` to represent omitted parts:

```bash
… NOT IN '{f27286a7-…}', '{927286a7-…}'
```

As Santiago points out, there is no need for a loop:

```bash
# Get all VM IDs, as an array, courtesy of 
# member-access enumeration
$vmIds = $VMs.vmid

# Transform the IDs to a string list such as:
#   '{f27286a7-…}', '{927286a7-…}'
# See below for an explanation.
$quotedIdList = $vmIds -replace '^|$', "'" -join ', '

# Now embed this string in your query via string interpolation
# and execute it.
# Note that you could embed the expression above directly in the string, with $(...)
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $Database `
              -Server $SQLServer `
              -Query @"
  UPDATE (table) SET Column1= 1, Column2= 0, column3 = GETDATE() 
  WHERE table.vmid NOT IN ($quotedIdList);"
"@
```

**Explanation** of the expression used to transform the array elements into single-line list (string) representation:

Note that, for added robustness, any `'` characters *embedded* in the array elements are escaped as **`''`**.

```bash
# -> String with the following verbatim content:
#       'three', 'o''clock'
@('three', "o'clock") -replace "'", "''" -replace '^|$', "'" -join ', '
```

- `-replace "'", "''"` doubles all embedded `'` characters in order to escape them.
- `-replace '^|$', "'"` uses the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) capabilities of the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to effectively enclose each element in `'...'`: `^|$` matches both (`|`) the position at the *start* (`^`) and *end* (`$`) of each element, and places a `'` there.
- `-join ', '` then places the separator string between the resulting, quoted elements, using the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator.

**Alternatively**, use the form suggested by Santiago:

```bash
"'" + (@('three', "o'clock") -replace "'", "''" -join "', '") + "'"
```

The above solutions shown **inside an [expandable (double-quoted) PowerShell string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)  (`"..."`)**, which requires use of `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--):

```bash
"list: $(@('three', "o'clock") -replace "'", "''" -replace '^|$', "'" -join ', ')"

# Note that the outer ' chars. can now be embedded directly in the string, 
# outside $(...)
"list: '$(@('three', "o'clock") -replace "'", "''" -join "', '")'"
```