# PowerShell Error - The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRow" could not be bound

Tags: sql, powershell

I am running below PS script

```
$prioryear = "select convert(char,(SELECT DATEADD(yy, -1,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))), 23) as prioryear"

--Above runs OK

Declaring prioryear as varchar in the query

$SQLquery = "
declare @prioryear varchar(50) = $prioryear_day
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
set @sql = 'select bp3.sedol, b.benchmark_name, b.description ,bp3.price as '' ' + @prioryear + ' ''
FROM
dbo.ds_benchmark_prices bp1
left join dbo.ds_benchmark_prices bp2 on bp1.sedol= bp2.sedol
left join dbo.ds_benchmark_prices bp3 on bp1.sedol= bp3.sedol
where convert(char,bp3.price_date,23)=$prioryear_day -- prior year 
order by b.sedol'
exec (@sql)
"
#Invokve statements are below - Running both below Invoke causes error. If I comment out second invoke statements, it runs OK. Seems an issue with the way I declared prioryear_day????

$prioryear_day=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $prioryear -ServerInstance "UKWAR01APWPD\WHERESCAPE" -Database RJISDWH

$SqlConnection=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQLquery -ServerInstance "UKWAR01APWPD\WHERESCAPE" -Database RJISDWH | Export-CSV $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

ERROR is

Invoke-Sqlcmd : The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRow" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRow" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure , Line 3.
At C:\Users\kbraxton\Desktop\Untitled8.ps1:56 char:16

- ... lConnection=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQLquery -ServerInstance "UKWAR01AP ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

--

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In your last snippet, you're using different variables in the `$SQLquery` definition than defined right above. E.g., `$prioryear_day` is the _result of an `Invoke-SqlQuery` call_, not a _string_, which explains your symptom. I assume you want to use the variables _without suffix `_day_`, such as `$prioryear` in this example.

Comment: Below also returns same error
$prioryear = "select convert(char,(SELECT DATEADD(yy, -1,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))), 23) as prioryear"
$previousquarter="select convert(char,(SELECT DATEADD(qq, -1,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))), 23) as previousquarter"
$lastquarter = "select convert(char,(SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))), 23) as lastquarter"

Comment: $lastquarterQuery=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $lastquarter -ServerInstance "UKWAR01APWPD\WHERESCAPE" -Database RJISDWH 
$previousquarterQuery=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $previousquarter -ServerInstance "UKWAR01APWPD\WHERESCAPE" -Database RJISDWH 
$SqlConnection=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQLquery -ServerInstance "UKWAR01APWPD\WHERESCAPE" -Database RJISDWH | Export-CSV $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
Above are my invoke statements

Comment: Still getting same error - what do I need to do to resolve it

Comment: Code in comments is hard to read, and in general you should instead [edit] your question directly to show your latest attempt and the latest symptom.

Comment: Why am I am getting below 
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRow" could not be bound.
 I have used
 $prioryear = "select convert(char,(SELECT DATEADD(yy, -1,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))), 23) as prioryear"
Then in my query declared as 
declare @prioryear varchar(50) = $prioryear_day
My invoke is 
$prioryearQuery=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $prioryear -ServerInstance "UKWAR01APWPD\WHERESCAPE" -Database RJISDWH 
$SqlConnection=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQLquery -ServerInstance "UKWAR01APWPD\WHERESCAPE" -Database RJISDWH

Comment: I always recommend debugging SQL queries using SQL Server Management Studio.  Get the queries working first with SSMS which has much better debugging messages than other utilities.  The queries are string and once you get working in SSMS it is simple to put the string into a powershell query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptom implies that you're trying to embed an *object of type [`System.Data.DataRow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataRow)* into your `$SQLquery` query *string*, which predictably fails, because such instances stringify *by their type name*, as reported in the error message.

Indeed, [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) returns a stream of `System.Data.Row` instances by default, so *you need to extract the column value of interest from it*, contained in the only row's `prioryear` column, in your case:

```
$prioryear_day = (
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $prioryear -ServerInstance "UKWAR01APWPD\WHERESCAPE" -Database RJISDWH
  ).prioryear
```

Now `$prioryear_day` is a string containing the actual query result, and you can embed it in your `$SQLquery` query string.

---

As an aside: Generally speaking, it's best to use *parameterized* queries to avoid the risk of SQL injection; unfortunately, `Invoke-SqlCmd` does *not* support this robustly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74816485/45375) for more information and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to convert the variables to datetime

```
 declare @prioryear datetime = '$prioryear_day'
declare @previousquarter datetime = '$previousquarter_day'
declare @lastquarter datetime = '$lastquarter_day
```

That resolved the issue.